# Polyfill for `position:fixed` in IE6 cause infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, position, css-position, internet-explorer-6, polyfills

Here is my code:

```
var target = document.getElementById("target");

window.onscroll = function () {

    var viewport = document.documentElement;
    var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    target.style.top = viewport.scrollTop + (viewportHeight - target.clientHeight) + "px";
}
```

In fact it could work, but when user scroll the page to the bottom, they could scroll the page infinitely. And the target still keep at the bottom of the page.

So what's wrong with my code? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think your main problem is the fact you're still developing for IE6. Please, let it die. Everyone will be better off

Comment: As much as I'm sure you probably have an idiot client specifying IE6 as a requirement, I promise you, they will not check. They won't be able to find an IE6 machine. This glitch sounds like a small price to pay for supporting IE6